# How I can make Start Page for My Application Like Visual studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

everyone know the **start page** of Visual studio it seems to be a web page, how I can make like it in my applications?

### Edit, Add more details:

let us say that I want to show the **recently opened forms**  or the **Tip of this day**, who I can do that, where to store the data and how to generate the HTML file?

Answer (score 2):

You could use IE as a control. Then you literally just design your start page as an HTML page.

Or you could anticipate VS 2010 and use WPF. That's what I've done for a forthcoming app - the start page is a `FlowDocument`, and it has some links injected into it for recent files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just need to drop the WebBrowser control in a Form and set some properties, mostly to prevent the contextual menu and things like that. Then you can *navigate* to any web page or just pass a string with the HTML you want the control to render.

Answer (score 1):

First, work out what you want to show, and where this information comes from (could be a bunch of reg keys, in the case of an MRU list, and an RSS feed for news headlines). You *could* then build an XML document off the back of that, feed it through an XSLT transform, and show resulting HTML in an embedded WebBrowser control.